# Unmarshalling a specific SOAP response in go

Tags: xml, go, soap, unmarshalling

I am trying to unmarshal the following SOAP response using the below structs.

```
var data = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3rg/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <doSendResponse>
            <doSendResult>Send OK.&lt;ReturnIDs&gt;c71cf425f5;e5e4dbb5ca&lt;/ReturnIDs&gt;</doSendResult>
        </doSendResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`

type ResponseBody struct {
    ResponseBody SendResponse `xml:"Body"`
}
type SendResponse struct {
    Result Result `xml:"doSendResponse"`
}
type Result struct {
    RawMessage string `xml:"doSendResult"`
}
```

All goes well until after the `<doSendResult>` element.
This particular tag contains a message i.e. "Send OK." and an HTML encoded `<ReturnIDs>` element, the problem isn't about the HTML encoded parts, I've already seen [this question and the accepted answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23585914/unmarshalling-escaped-xml)
My problem is that I can't manage to extract both the message and the return IDs.

I tried to use the approach suggested in the previously mentioned question but I failed, [Here](https://play.golang.org/p/iY4LvUArM3) is what I tried so far.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

var data = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3rg/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <doSendResponse>
            <doSendResult>Send OK.&lt;ReturnIDs&gt;c71cf425f5;e5e4dbb5ca&lt;/ReturnIDs&gt;</doSendResult>
        </doSendResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`

type ResponseBody struct {
    ResponseBody SendResponse `xml:"Body"`
}
type SendResponse struct {
    Result Result `xml:"doSendResponse"`
}
type Result struct {
    RawMessage string `xml:"doSendResult"`
}
type RawMessage struct {
    IDs     string `xml:"ReturnIDs"`
}

func main() {
    var response ResponseBody
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &response)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", response)

    var rawMessage RawMessage
    err = xml.Unmarshal([]byte(response.ResponseBody.Result.RawMessage), &rawMessage)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", rawMessage)

}
```

Output:
`{ResponseBody:{Result:{RawMessage:Send OK.<ReturnIDs>c71cf425f5;e5e4dbb5ca</ReturnIDs>}}}
{IDs:}`

I also tried to Unesacpe the response, then tried to unmarshal it, it partially works, but there are 3 main problems with this approach:

1. It's too slow
2. I could only either [get the ReturnIDs](https://play.golang.org/p/rG7_3uSnTA) or [the message](https://play.golang.org/p/t2b2xfF704), not both.
3. I believe it's just an ugly hack and there must be a better way to do that (That I'm not aware of, yet.)

So, How can I extract both values for the message (Send OK.) and the `<ReturnIDs>`?

Comment: an ugly hack for an ugly format. I don't see how you d do otherwise.

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: At least leave a comment on why you just downvoted my question.
Simply downvoting doesn't help me to understand what's wrong, thus it is not constructive.

Comment: Best to put your code in the question. At least the core of the relevant part. Playground links are useful as additions, but playground links don't last forever, and your question will.

Comment: And BTW, my downvote was accompanied with a comment. But that's not a requirement, and asking for that is just noise.

Comment: @Flimzy Thanks for pointing that. I'll include the code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decode the doSendResult tag content with multiple ways, but I did a example:

[play.golang.org/p/NC9YrWqK0k](https://play.golang.org/p/NC9YrWqK0k)

I defined two type corresponding to the tags inside body of the soap envelop:

```
type (
    SendResponse struct {
        SendResult SendResult `xml:"Body>doSendResponse>doSendResult"`
    }

    SendResult struct {
        RawMessage string   `xml:"-"`
        Text       string   `xml:"-"`
        IDS        []string `xml:"-"`
    }
)
```

The type `SendResult` has a custom unmarshal function to read the raw message and populate the struct

```
func (sr *SendResult) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    var raw string
    d.DecodeElement(&raw, &start)

    var st struct {
        Contents  string `xml:",chardata"`
        ReturnIDs string `xml:"ReturnIDs"`
    }

    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte("<xml>"+raw+"</xml>"), &st)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    sr.RawMessage = raw
    sr.Text = st.Contents
    sr.IDS = strings.Split(st.ReturnIDs, ";")

    return nil
}
```

This is the how to use:

```
const data = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3rg/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <doSendResponse>
            <doSendResult>Send OK.&lt;ReturnIDs&gt;c71cf425f5;e5e4dbb5ca&lt;/ReturnIDs&gt;</doSendResult>
        </doSendResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`

func main() {
    var sendResponse SendResponse

    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &sendResponse)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", sendResponse)
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, Thank, your answer helped me a lot.
Based on this http://herman.asia/efficient-string-concatenation-in-go, I used the buffer approach instead of simple concatenation. Although the performance gain might not be much with the current load, I guess it would pay off with higher loads at certain times.

Answer (score 0):

Since the contents of the `doSendResult` element appears to be a "custom" format (as opposed to a well-formed document such as HTML, XML, etc.) regular expressions might be a good way to parse the result here.

For example:

```
type SendResult struct {
  Status    string
  ReturnIds []string
}

var doSendResultRegex = regexp.MustCompile("^Send (.*?)\\.<ReturnIDs>(.*?)</ReturnIDs>$")

func ParseSendResult(s string) *SendResult {
  ss := doSendResultRegex.FindStringSubmatch(s)
  if ss == nil {
    return nil
  }
  return &SendResult{
    Status:    ss[1],
    ReturnIds: strings.Split(ss[2], ";"),
  }
}

// ...
fmt.Println("%#v\n", ParseSendResult(response.Result.RawMessage))
// &main.SendResult{
//   Status:    "OK",
//   ReturnIds: []string{"c71cf425f5", "e5e4dbb5ca"}
// }
```

Of course, you may want to modify the `doSendResultRegex` expression depending on other examples of that data but the code above should illustrate the idea.

Comment: Sorry for the delay to respond, Thanks for your answer but I guess using regex may have a performance hit compared to using a custom parser.